# Recursive summation returning StackOverflow for large numbers

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to implement the following function:
`f(k) = 1 * (k/1) + 2 * (k/2) + ... + n * (k/n)`

So for example, if k = 5, we have `f(5) = 1 * (5/1) + 2 * (5/2) + ... + 4 * (5/4)`.

(Note that k/n here uses integer division, so the result has no fractional part. For example: 8/3
would equal 2.)

I tried to use a recursive function and it works for small numbers, but when I use numbers like 200,000, it breaks and gives me a StackOverflow Error.

Here's my code (start is basically initialized as k-1):

```
static int price(int k, int start) {
        if(start == 1) {
            return n;
        }
        return (start)*(k/start) + price(k, start-1);
    }
```

This is part of a bigger code, where I need to calculate the price and check if it's greater than the amount of money, C, I have and if it's greater, then I need to decrement.

If you need more clarification, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: what is k? is it `n` or `start`? Your formula has 1 param, but your function has two. Sorry I dont understand :-)

Comment: what is the value of start when k=200,000

Comment: why dont you just multiply k by n, that seems be be the mathematical simplification and answer of your case.

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited it now. Basically, given a value k, we run price (k, k-1) to begin with. So for example, if k = 5, we have `f(5) = 1 * (5/1) + 2 * (5/2) + ... + 4 * (5/4)`. Please note how the formula ends

Comment: Your code is trying to calculate `200000 * 199999`, which is `39999800000`. The limit of 32-bit integer is `2147483647`.

Comment: or by what you say about start, the answer is (k-1) times k

Comment: you can change the data type, but why even use recursion? answer is start times K

Comment: @ArunRajagopal: On ideal rational numbers, yes, `i * (k / i)` is `k`. On floating point numbers, not quite (though you are just measuring the floating point error.) But OP is using integers, where `i * (k / i)` is rounding down `k` to the adjacent lower integer divisible by `i`.

Comment: @Amadan the data type is integer in OPs post

Comment: @ArunRajagopal That is exactly what I am saying. `5 * (17 / 5)` is `15`, not `17`. Your math does not work with integers.

Comment: @Amadan I have to mention that K/j here uses integer division, so the result has no fractional part. For example: 8/3 would equal 2.

Comment: @Amadan I agree, but I assume OP does not mean `/` operator in programming, but mathematical division, that why OP says "I'm trying to implement a mathematical formula:"

Comment: @Amadan ok, you were right, OP has clarified

Comment: Also, @Amadan it's not as easy as 200000*199999, this won't work given the conditions of the formula.  I am so confused now because long doesn't work either

Comment: @nTuply you might want to change the phrasing from "mathematical formula" to something more programmatic

Comment: @ArunRajagopal I edited it now. Should be easier to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could change from recursion to an iterative approach:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int it = start; it > 0; it--) {
    sum += it * (k / it);
}
```

This way, you avoid putting method calls onto the stack.

[This](https://freecontent.manning.com/stack-safe-recursion-in-java/) might be a good read to learn about the JVM's stack limits:

> Of course, method calls may be deeply nested. Is there a limit to method nesting depth? Yes. The limit is the size of the stack. In current situations, the limit is somewhere around a few thousands of levels, although it is possible to increase this limit by configuring the stack size. [...] Default stack size varies between 320k and 1024k depending on the version of Java and the system used. For a 64 bits Java 8 program with minimal stack usage, the maximum number of nested method calls is about 7 000. Generally, we don’t need more, excepted in very specific cases. **One such case is recursive method calls**.

Comment: Would that be faster in practice? I will give it a try now

Comment: It might be faster due to less overhead for the method calls. For sure it avoids running into stack overflows.

Comment: This actually works and it's very fast. The only problem I'm having is I have a test about those and the system they use check for the speed, so in the grand scheme of things, I wanted to know if there is something fast than the loop? Also would it make sense to use this loop as part of another recursive function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are asking. I don't think that you can speed up this for loop except by first simplifying the calculation formula with some clever math.